# Finding radius of convergence to a power series.

Tags: power-series

Given a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ satisfies:

$$\ a_{n+2}+ ( n^2 -\alpha^2 )a_n = 0 $$

For all $\ n\geq 2 $

Assume $\ \alpha $ is an integer.

What is the radius of convergence ofthe power series?

I tried using the ratio test to calculate the radius of convergence but I am stuck on the very first step. Any help or hints will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Don't you have the initial values ?

Comment: No initial numbers were given in the question. And that is why it is giving me such a hard time.